# Error message when trying to add a service reference to a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I have a WCF data service in a project in a solution, and after creating a WPF project and trying to add the service reference to it, I get this error message:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Full error text [here](http://pastebin.com/x3v9qHKT)

These are the steps I followed to create the projects and the solution:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465161.aspx

I've gotten to the "Creating the WPF Client Application" section, step 10, where the process fails to add the reference. That is when I get the error message, at the point of adding the service as a reference.
If I access the service path in the browser it says

> "Request error. The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."

My web.config in the service project is the original, added by VS.

Does anyone have any ideas, how to fix this?

Comment: It seems as though you are trying to debug the server from the client.  Are you able to start a debug session on the server, either locally or remotely?

Comment: Have you looked at (or requested access to view) the logs on the server?  95% of the time looking at the event viewer will give you a really good idea, if not the exact cause, of the error.

Comment: I'm just following the steps in the walkthrough, I don't think I'm debugging the server from the client. I have tried debugging it, but the only file I can put a breakpoint in is the .svc file. Where can I find the logs of the server?